# Create a blinking object with OpenGL and C++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, graphics2d

Admittedly I am not very familiar with graphics programming, although I'm working on modifying an existing project (C++ w/ OpenGL) to fit some of my personal needs.

Basically multiple balls are drawn to the screen and then move from one side to the other. I plan on choosing some based on a condition and would like them to flash/blink as they go across.

I can't seem to find an answer to this through Google or on this site. Any insight, ideas, or posts you can refer me to would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried keeping a timer and changing their colors every time a certain time interval passes?

Comment: Could you put in some of your current implementation so we can work on something rather than starting from scratch.